# Finding earliest date, before another date, in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to identify the earliest date in a given column, that occurs before the date in another column, for the same individual ID.

As an example for the same theory, but different specifics - say a person shops at a store regularly but only uses a coupon sometimes. I have a record for each visit and whether they used a coupon. For each visit, I want to know the earliest past date they have used a coupon (disregarding times they used a coupon at future visits).

Here is the data I have:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
ID & visit\_date & coupon\_date \\
1  & 3/1/2018    &              \\
1  & 2/1/2018    & 2/1/2018     \\
1  & 1/1/2018    &              \\
2  & 7/1/2018    & 7/1/2018     \\
2  & 6/1/2018    &              \\
3  & 12/1/2018   &              \\
3  & 11/1/2018   & 11/1/2018    \\
3  & 9/1/2018    &              \\
3  & 8/1/2018    & 8/1/2018    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Here is how I'd like it to look:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
ID & visit\_date & most\_recent\_coupon\_date \\
1  & 3/1/2018    & 2/1/2018                   \\
1  & 2/1/2018    & 2/1/2018                   \\
1  & 1/1/2018    &                            \\
2  & 7/1/2018    & 7/1/2018                   \\
2  & 6/1/2018    &                            \\
3  & 12/1/2018   & 11/1/2018                  \\
3  & 11/1/2018   & 11/1/2018                  \\
3  & 9/1/2018    & 8/1/2018                   \\
3  & 8/1/2018    & 8/1/2018                  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I've tried using max, lead/lag, etc. but I can't find a way to get the max date before the date recorded in another column.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Latex format is not supported on Stackoverflow. You may add data in a reproducible format using `dput`. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the **`dplyr`** library and the **`zoo`** library:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

newdf <- na.locf(mutate_all(df, list(~na_if(.,""))), fromLast=T)
newdf[strptime(newdf$visit_date, format="%d/%m/%Y") < strptime(newdf$coupon_date, format="%d/%m/%Y"), 'coupon_date'] <- ''
```

Output:

```
> newdf
  ID visit_date coupon_date
1  1   3/1/2018    2/1/2018
2  1   2/1/2018    2/1/2018
3  1   1/1/2018            
4  2   7/1/2018    7/1/2018
5  2   6/1/2018            
6  3  12/1/2018   11/1/2018
7  3  11/1/2018   11/1/2018
8  3   9/1/2018    8/1/2018
9  3   8/1/2018    8/1/2018
>
```